# Displayed ListView as PivotData (XAML, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, pivot

I have displayed data inside `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListUsers}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="ReadTime" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReadTime}" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="Stanowisko" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="Counter" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PosCou}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It looks like:

```
ReadTime | Position |PosCou
---------------------------
01022019 |  PosA    | 10
01022019 |  PosB    | 20
01022019 |  PosC    | 30
...
01032019 |  PosA    | 12
01032019 |  PosB    | 21
01032019 |  PosC    | 33
```

Now I want to `displayed exactly the same data` but in view like `Pivot Data`:

```
      |01022019 | 01032019 | ...
---------------------------------
PosA  |  10     |   12     | ...
PosB  |  20     |   21     | ...
PosC  |  30     |   33     | ...
...
```

How I can do that?

My Linq query:

```
 public IList<GroupUser> GetList(ICollection<User> UserList)
        {
            GroupUsersList = UserList
                            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ReadTime, x.Position })
                            .Select(group => new GroupUser
                                            {
                                                ReadTime = group.Key.ReadTime,
                                                Position = group.Key.Stanowisko,
                                                PosCou = group.Count()
                                            })
                            .ToList();
            return new List<GroupUser>(GroupUsersList);
        }
```

`IEnumerable<User> listUsers`:

```
public class User
{
 public string ReadTime { get; set; }
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public string LName { get; set; }
 public string FName { get; set; }
 public string Position { get; set; }
 public string City { get; set; }
 public string Country { get; set; }
 public string Car { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where do you struggle? What have you tryed?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Can you pivot your data directly in your DB?

Comment: yes MVVM, I had Linq query (please see update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How I can do that?

You use a type that represents a row in the pivoted view and transform your source collection. If the number of columns is dynamic, you could use a `DataTable`.

Given an `IEnumerable<User>`, the following method should return you a pivoted `DataTable`:

```
private static DataTable TransformData(IEnumerable<User> listUsers)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Position"));

    Dictionary<string, DataRow> positions = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>();
    foreach (var user in listUsers)
    {
        DataColumn column = dataTable.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.ColumnName == user.ReadTime);
        if (column == null)
        {
            column = new DataColumn(user.ReadTime);
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        DataRow row;
        if (!positions.TryGetValue(user.Position, out row))
        {
            row = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            row[0] = user.Position;
            positions.Add(user.Position, row);
        }

        object o = row[column];
        int posCou = o == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(o);
        row[column] = posCou + user.PosCou;
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

You could then replace the `ListView` with a `DataGrid` that auto generates the dynamic columns, or explicitly create the columns yourself in the view:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataTable.DefaultView}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: in my MVVM to `connect ListView` I did `ICollection<GroupUser> ListUsers { get; set;}`....how to do now with `DataTable.DefaultView`?

Comment: Just return a `DataView` or an `IEnumerable` from the property: `public DataView ListUsers => dataTable.DefaultView`;

Comment: I got error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field...`

Comment: got it, now it's for line `int posCou = o == DBNull...` => `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`

Comment: So what is the value of `o` when you debug your code? Also note that I provided an *example*. SO is not a code writing service...

Comment: it's `1000073710000738`...? when Im looking on `column'` I see date `2019-01-03`

Comment: There is obviously something in your input data then. Please provide some sample data if you need any further help.

Comment: I'm passing `IEnumerable<User> listUsers`, I have update Q and provide class of `User`

Comment: You need to provide an example of `listUsers`, i.e. the actual *data*. But I believe that your original question has already been answered. You need to transform the data. I gave you an example of how to do this.

Comment: thanks, I see that problem I just have is that as result for all rows Im getting `1`

Comment: -@mm8 please update your answer and do like `row[column] = posCou +1` => it's working great :)